# On click get list values and auto submit form with values

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to auto send values in a form in a hidden field.

This is my first form. When I submit this form 2 action occurred 1.) trigger js - onclick="displayResult()" and 2.) send form to update.php

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
    <select name=category[] id=category multiple="multiple" class=master>
        <?php   
        $file = fopen("category.csv", "r");
        while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $category = $row[0];
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category;?>"><?php echo $category;?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Save File" onclick="displayResult()" name="submit" >
</form>
```

This is my js and I tried to auto submit form with adding document.getElementById("myform").submit(); When I do var_dump I get NULL

```
<script>
    function displayResult() {
    var options = document.getElementById('master').options;

    var values = [];
    var i = 0, len = options.length;

    while (i < len)
    {
      values.push(options[i++].value);
    }

    txt=(values.join(','));
        alert(txt);
        document.getElementById('masterlist').value = txt;
        document.getElementById("myform").submit();
        }
    </script>
```

This is the form I need to auto send values via above js but not working. Please need help

```
<form action="update.php" method="post" name="myform" id="myform">
        <input type="hidden" name="masterlist" id="masterlist" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, you should add necessary `""`

   ```
   <select name=category[] id="category" multiple="multiple" class="master">
   ```
2. Than change submit to **hidden** and **remove onClick**

   ```
   <input type="submit" value="Save File" name="submit" hidden>
   ```
3. Next, add **another button** which have an **onClick** event

   ```
   <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="displayResult();">
   ```
4. At the end - fix your JS. You should refer to the id **'category'**, but you're refering to the class **'master'**, using getElementById()

   ```
   var options = document.getElementById('category').options;
   ```

Working fiddle (little changed for fiddle purposes): [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/p7uLqjht/)

Comment: Thanx you this work but how do I target the other forms I have about 46 forms  I will edit my post to show what I mean